# How can I find the first non-repeating character in a string?

Tags: string, function, perl, duplicates

I need to write a function that returns the first non-repeating character in a string (case-insensitively). For example, for the string `"Thanks for visiting"` it should return `"h"`.

Comment: So "T" and "t" are treated as repeating?

Comment: This sounds a bit like homework... if so, please use the homework tag.

Comment: What part of this problem are you stuck on? Have you got as far as realizing you need to count each unique character in the string?

Comment: More importantly, have you gotten as far as realizing that the graders to who handle papers for your class have probably heard of SO, too?

Answer (score 2):

You could make a pass over the characters in the string and store counts for each character (in a case-insensitive manner) in a hash. Then make another pass and return the first character with the count of 1:

```
sub get_char {
    my ($string) = @_;
    my @chars = split //, $string;
    my %chars;
    ++$chars{ lc() } for @chars;
    $chars{ lc() } == 1 && return $_ for @chars;
}
```

Apparently, this approach takes `O(n)` time and `O(n)` extra space.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub { 
    # This assumes non-repeating means consecutive-repeating.
    # non-consecutive-repeating is too boring to answer
    my $string_copy = $_[0];
    $string_copy =~ s/(.)(\1)+//g; 
    return substr($string_copy ,0, 1)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the OP's example.

Comment: @mobrule - please see the comments on top :)
For OP's example, the first non-consecutive-repeating character is "T", not "h". I didn't feel like answering his absolutely basic homework question that already has an answer posted and instead answered a somewhat more difficult one

Answer (score 0):

Using `substr()` and `index()`:

```
sub get_it {
    my $string = shift;
    for my $i ( 0 .. length($string) - 1 ) {
        my $char = substr $string, $i, 1;
        return $char if index( $string, $char, $i + 1 ) >= 0;
    }
}
```